# Is Thunderbird/Sunbird the only one that can read and write .ics files on network folder?

Tags: outlook, icalendar, thunderbird-lightning

I have an ics calendar file that is store on a network folder.
Thunderbird/Sunbird can read and write entries very well.

Now i am looking for an alternative.
It seem to be that Thinderbird (with Lighning) or Sunbird, is the only one that can write 
ics file. Outlook, e.g can only read the calendar file.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook can create ICS files just fine either through its UI (File | Save As) or programmatically (AppointmentItem.SaveAs(..., olICal)

Comment: yes, that's right. Outlook can export to ics. But once when i load the ics file from network folder, the calendar is nor writeable

Comment: Not writable in what sense? Can't you drag an ICS file to the Calendar folder?

Comment: you can open the ICS file, but you can't add an event etc.

Comment: Add where? Directly to the ICS file? Of course not, Outlook does not natively store its data in ICS files. If you add a new appointment to the Calendar folder, you can then save it as an ICS file.